# What does Captain Toad say at the start of each level?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world, captain-toad-treasure-tracker

At the beginning of Captain Toad levels in **Super Mario 3D World** and **Captain Toad: Treasure Tracker**, Captain Toad says a short phrase that almost certainly ends with the word "adventure".

You can hear the **Super Mario 3D World** version of the phrase at the beginning of

, and the seemingly-identical sound bite from **Captain Toad: Treasure Tracker** at the beginning of, say,

.

My first guess was "Let's Adventure!", but upon careful listening, it seems like the phrase may end with "for adventure!". On Gamefaqs, there was a discussion ([here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805615-captain-toad-treasure-tracker/70748134)) in which "Time for adventure!" and "Ready for adventure!" were both proposed, and I don't feel fully confident about either one.

### What phrase is Captain Toad actually saying?

I'm not just looking for more opinions; some evidence would be great. Perhaps a quote from a Nintendo official/promotional materials (maybe it's written on a foreign box for **Captain Toad: Treasure Tracker**?) or some work on analyzing the audio (slowing it down? a spectrogram?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What phrase is Captain Toad actually saying?

**Captain Toad is saying "Ready for adventure."** I found this out by slowing the playback on the Youtube video, and others, to .5x and maxing the volume. It took a few playbacks to get the full phrase in one round as it sometimes clips the first word or last. Also note, during playback Youtube seems to handle slow audio better at lower resolutions.

Comment: Is there a method of slowing down the youtube video you would recommend to make this clear? I found youtubeslow.com, but if you could upload a sound file of the clip slowed down that seemed decisive, or similar, I think that would settle things completely.

Comment: I used the embedded capability on the gear icon in the youtube player.